# Unexplained InnoDB timeouts

Tags: mysql, query, innodb, locked-objects

I've been seeing some very basic updates timing out lately and have not been able to determine the cause. An example:

//# Query_time: 51 Lock_time: 0 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0

`UPDATE photos SET position = position + 1 WHERE (photo_album_id = 40470);`

The same log has no entries with a Lock_time > 0. Running `show innodb status` does not reveal any related locks either. This problem appears to be affecting at least 5 different tables based on my app server logs (which show a `Mysql::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded` error related to each corresponding entry in the mysql-slow log).

Any idea on where to go from here? I'm hitting dead-ends in all directions. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `photo_album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) default 'Untitled',
  `description` text,
  `credit` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `photo_file_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `photo_content_type` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `photo_file_size` int(11) default NULL,
  `photo_updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `position` int(11) default '0',
  `views` int(11) default '0',
  `folder` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `published_at` datetime default NULL,
  `created_at` datetime default NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `album_published` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `comment_count` int(11) default '0',
  `audio_file_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `audio_content_type` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `audio_file_size` int(11) default NULL,
  `audio_updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `cover` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `slug` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `comments_count` int(11) default '0',
  `delete_from_s3` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `batch` int(11) default NULL,
  `audio` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_album_published` (`album_published`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_batch` (`batch`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_comment_count` (`comment_count`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_delete_from_s3` (`delete_from_s3`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_photo_album_id` (`photo_album_id`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_published` (`published`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_published_at` (`published_at`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_type` (`type`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42830 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Silly question: what indexes do you have on that table?

Comment: Hi, please see the edit.

Comment: Hmm, this is annoying because this is so easy to diagnose in Oracle, you just set 10046 trace level 12 and it will tell you *exactly* what it's doing. I'll have some more of a think about it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with an InnoDB table, I think it has something to do with the increment. I'm doing: `UPDATE table SET <field>=<field>+1 WHERE <pk_field>=1;` My table is much simpler though. At random this causes the same error you're getting. My version is: 5.1.39. I'm spending some time today trying to figure it out so I'll update if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks, pls let me know what you find out, we still haven't figured this one out.

Comment: Same here, I'm at a loss. One of the problems is that it happens to us at 2:30am during a cron job, so I won't be able to actually monitor it in progress until this weekend.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with my innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit being set to 0?

Comment: I found some promising leads searching google for `innodb primary key increment update lock -"autoincrement" -"auto increment"`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is really late, but you really need to capture the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; during that query to see why it's waiting.

If it happens a lot during a specific time, it would be easy to just grab that output every x seconds and hope you capture it (or perhaps artificially generate the load).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say normalize database - and add propper indizes.

A single photo doesnt need to carry all info about the album it belongs to - this cries for a separate table for albums - and a relation table that only contains the mapping of photoID<->albumID
the same applies - if included - to the photographer  (separate table and a mapping table between photoID and photographerID

It may look at first that your queries become a bit more complicated but the information is now logically divided and at the same time you use a RDBMS for what it is about .. data and their relations